# Working with dates in PHP, how many hours old is date/time stamp?

Tags: php, datetime, date

Ok, I am storing a Date/Time in a MySQL TEXT field. I want to be able to check if the date stored in the database is atleast 48 hours from the current date/time. Here is some code:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
$dtformat = "F jS, Y - g:i A";

$datetime = date($dtformat);
?>
```

The value of $datetime is sent to MySQL and placed in a TEXT column, I would use MySQL DATETIME, but the timezone needs to be different, depending on the users location. So I figured I would make my timestamp in PHP. An example output would be `January 11th, 2011 - 6:24 PM`

How would I take the current date/time in PHP and find out if my timestamp `January 11th, 2011 - 6:24 PM` is atleast 48 hours old?

Thanks

Comment: "Ok, I am storing a Date/Time in a MySQL TEXT field." --- Omg.

Comment: You'll have more work to do if you aren't storing dates as the `date` type or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
$dtformat = "F jS, Y - g:i A";

$datetime = date($dtformat);

$i_datetime = strtotime($datetime);
$i_48_hours = strtotime('now -48 hours');
if ($i_datetime < $i_48_hours) 
{ 
    echo "The date $datetime is older than 48 hours old.";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, had to strip the "-" out of my timestamp between date and time for it to work. but it did! at this point changing the database would have ruined my data

Comment: @Mike L.: "would have ruined my data" --- well, create another blank `timestamp` field and fill it with php script. If you don't change your terrible schema now - you'll never do it in the future.

Answer (score 4):

First, you should be storing the data and time in the appropriate `timestamp` field and **not** a text field.

Moving on...
You could compare the dates like this:

```
if(strtotime($dateFromDatabase." + 48 hours") <= strtotime("now")) {
  //It's at least 48 hours old, do your stuff
}
```

Comment: `strtotime("now")` looks a bit overcomplicated ;-) (I'm implying on using `time()` instead)

Comment: Yes, I also upvoted you as you've given *correct* answer to his question, but anyway I think it is not right to help him doing such weird things.

Answer (score 1):

> I would use MySQL DATETIME, but the timezone needs to be different, depending on the users location"

so use mysql `timestamp` date type, it is designed for such special purposes.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/timestamp.html

I don't think it is any reason to continue following current terrible solution. Better rewrite your code for using `timestamp`.

Comment: I tried this originally, There is nothing on the MySQL site that lists possible values for `SET SESSION time_zone =` do you know of such a list?

Comment: @Mike L.: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations here at least, but abbreviations and tz names you can use only if administrator has imported timezones database (it is quite rare). Otherwise you can use just specify the offset in hours there `SET time_zone='+10:00'`